# Uses command line arguments to accept the desired number of rows and columns in java

Tags: java

it contains two java classes: TwoDMethods.java and TwoDTest.java

for TwoDMethods.java

1. The fill method fills the entire array with randomly-selected double values
   between 0.0 and 100.0
2. The toString method returns a string representation of the two-dimensional
   array, with the rows separated by "\n" and the columns vertically aligned
3. The sumColumns method returns a one-dimensional array containing the sum
   of each column of the given two-dimensional array
4. The sumRows method returns a one-dimensional array containing the sum of
   each row of the given two-dimensional array
5. The minValue method returns the smallest number in the given array
6. The maxValue method returns the largest number in the given array

I finished TwoDMethods.java but I am not sure how to write TwoDTest.java

and all methods should be static but the toString method always goes wrong when I add static.

For example, in TwoDTest.java using the following command:

java TwoDTest 3 4

the output will be:

```
toString() result:
    
    41.23 72.99 8.60  38.62
    70.32 52.00 38.63 90.60
    72.98 6.54  94.50 91.34

Column sums:
    
    184.53 131.54 141.73 220.56

Row sums:
    
    161.45 251.55 265.36

    Smallest number: 6.54
    Largest number:  94.50
```

this is TwoDMethods.java:

```
public class TwoDMethods {

static int row, col;
static double sumRow, sumCol;

static double[][] array = new double[row][col];

public static void fill() {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            array[i][j] = (double) (Math.random() * 100.00);
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String method2 ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            method2 += String.format("%8.2f", array[row][col]) + " ";
        }
        method2 += "\n";
    }
    return method2;
}

public static double[] sumRows() {
    double[] rowArray = new double[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        sumRow = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            sumRow = sumRow + array[i][j];
        }
        rowArray[i] = sumRow;
    }
    return rowArray;
}

public static double[] sumColumns() {
    double[] colArray = new double[col];

    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        sumCol = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            sumCol = sumCol + array[j][i];
        }
        colArray[i] = sumCol;
    }
    return colArray;
}

public static double minValue() {
    double minValue = array[0][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array[j].length; i++) {
            if (array[j][i] < minValue) {
                minValue = array[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}

public static double maxValue() {
    double maxValue = array[0][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array[j].length; i++) {
            if (array[j][i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = array[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the report of what you did. Where is the question?

Comment: `toString()` is a method that **every** class inherits from `Object`. Its main purpose is to override it (like you do) It's not static and so you can't implement a static version of it either.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to make the methods static nor the members of class `TwoDMethods`. Here is my suggested code. It is basically your code with occurrences of `static` removed plus I added a constructor. The constructor initializes the class members. Note that you had an error in method `toString` in this line:

```java
method2 += String.format("%8.2f", array[row][col]) + " ";
```

It should be:

```java
method2 += String.format("%8.2f", array[i][j]) + " ";
```

I changed it in the below code.

```java
public class TwoDMethods {
    int row, col;
    double sumRow, sumCol;
    double[][] array = new double[row][col];

    public TwoDMethods(int numRows, int numColumns) {
        row = numRows;
        col = numColumns;
        array = new double[row][col];
    }

    public void fill() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                array[i][j] = (double) (Math.random() * 100.00);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String method2 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                method2 += String.format("%8.2f", array[i][j]) + " ";
            }
            method2 += "\n";
        }
        return method2;
    }

    public double[] sumRows() {
        double[] rowArray = new double[row];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            sumRow = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                sumRow = sumRow + array[i][j];
            }
            rowArray[i] = sumRow;
        }
        return rowArray;
    }

    public double[] sumColumns() {
        double[] colArray = new double[col];
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
            sumCol = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                sumCol = sumCol + array[j][i];
            }
            colArray[i] = sumCol;
        }
        return colArray;
    }

    public double minValue() {
        double minValue = array[0][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array[j].length; i++) {
                if (array[j][i] < minValue) {
                    minValue = array[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
        return minValue;
    }

    public double maxValue() {
        double maxValue = array[0][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array[j].length; i++) {
                if (array[j][i] > maxValue) {
                    maxValue = array[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

And here is the class you requested, `TwoDTest`.

```java
public class TwoDTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: TwoDTest row cols");
        }
        else {
            int numRows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int numColumns = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            TwoDMethods twoD = new TwoDMethods(numRows, numColumns);
            twoD.fill();
            System.out.print(twoD);
            System.out.println("Column sums:");
            double[] sumColumns = twoD.sumColumns();
            for (double sum : sumColumns) {
                System.out.printf("%8.2f ", sum);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Row sums:");
            double[] sumRows = twoD.sumRows();
            for (double sum : sumRows) {
                System.out.printf("%8.2f ", sum);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Smallest number: " + twoD.minValue());
            System.out.println("Largest number: " + twoD.maxValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I launch class `TwoDTest` as follows:

```
java TwoDTest 3 4
```

And I get the following output:

```
   96.83    11.96    50.86    43.26 
   89.06    84.86    30.68    59.61 
   63.51    96.09    49.93    32.19 
Column sums:
  249.39   192.92   131.47   135.05 
Row sums:
  202.90   264.21   241.72 
Smallest number: 11.962167522763945
Largest number: 96.82621497529537
```